# Adobe Flex 4.6 WebService request timeout

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, timeout, flex4.6

The code to get connected to my WebService (Lotus Notes Database) is created by the Flash Builder over "Data/Connect with WebService...". All works fine, but I have a problem to increase the request timeout. The API says that you can set the request timeout like this:

```
_serviceControl.requestTimeout = 300;
```

On a iOS (iPad) it seems to be work all fine. But if I run my app on desktop or on an android smartphone this only works if I set up the request timeout lower than ~30 seconds. If I don't set up the request timeout or higher than 30 and my app needs longer than 30 seconds to wait for an answer/result the "_serviceControl" fires an FaultEvent with the message:

```
body = ""  
clientId = "DirectHTTPChannel0"  
correlationId = "CDED773E-34E5-56F8-D521-4FFC393D7565"  
destination = ""  
extendedData = (null)  
faultCode = "Server.Error.Request"  
faultDetail = "Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: "http://...?OpenWebService" errorID=2032]. URL: "http://...?OpenWebService"  
faultString = "HTTP request error"  
headers = (Object)#1  
DSStatusCode = 0  
messageId = "91D11378-49D4-EDF7-CE7A-4FFCB09EBC47"  
rootCause = (flash.events::IOErrorEvent)#2  
bubbles = false  
cancelable = false  
currentTarget = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3  
bytesLoaded = 0  
bytesTotal = 0  
data = ""  
dataFormat = "text"  
errorID = 2032  
eventPhase = 2  
target = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3  
text = "Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: "http://...?OpenWebService"  
type = "ioError"  
timestamp = 0  
timeToLive = 0
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem on the production system. So I think the reason is my development environment.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, requestTimeout didn't work.

If someone is looking for an answer, this configuration works fine for me :

```
import flash.net.URLRequestDefaults;

URLRequestDefaults.idleTimeout = 120000; //note this value represents milliseconds (120 secs)
```

Have a look here for more details : [Flex HTTPService times out anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820715/flex-httpservice-times-out-anyway)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you briefly describe the actual answer in addition to the link to the other Stack Overflow question?

Answer (score 0):

Though it seems to be assumed that requestTimeout doesn't work. It actually does... the 1st time.

After the 1st request, the requestTimeout is set in

```
HTTPService.channelSet.currentChannel.requestTimeout
```

If you have to change the timeout, you will want to do it there.

To see the specific offending code, see AbstractOperation.getDirectChannelSet(). Even for different instances of HTTPService, it pulls from:

```
private static var _directChannelSet:ChannelSet;
```

_directChannelSet is only instantiated once, and the requestTimeout on it is only set on creation, so even if you change the requestTimeout on HTTPService, it won't reflect in the request.