# Time out when calling a Web service

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, flash, builder

I have a problem when I am using the webservice from a mobile App Im developing in Flex Builder.

I have the following code for a Web service

```
<s:CallResponder id="readAllPedidosErpResult"    result="readAllPedidosErpResult_resultHandler(event)"  fault="sincFailResult_faultHandler(event)"/>

protected function readAllPedidosErp():void
{
    readAllPedidosErpResult.token = xEasyERPMobileAppWS.readAllPedidosErp
    (readFechaSincronizacionPedidoErp(),sC.readComercialUsuario());
}

protected function readAllPedidosErpResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    var result:ArrayCollection;
    var c:PedidoWSMobile;

    if(event.token.result is ArrayCollection)
    {
        result = event.token.result as ArrayCollection;
        if(result!=null)
        {                                               
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
    continueToNext(15);
}
```

The problem I get is that xEasyERPMobileAppWS.readAllPedidosErp(readFechaSincronizacionPedidoErp(),sC.readComercialUsuario()); takes almost 2 minutes to get the answer but after 30 seconds (more or less) does not wait more and I got a fault (sincFailResult_faultHandler(event)).

How can I give more time to the CallResponder to wait the answer from the Web Service I am calling?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fault I get is "soap response cannot be decoded. raw response"

Answer (score 2):

I´ve just found the solution in another thread.

FYI: [Adobe Flex 4.6 WebService request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598860/adobe-flex-4-6-webservice-request-timeout)

Thanks anyways!