# Httpservice timeout with 2032 stream error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.6, httpservice

I have a flash web application and I use HttpService to upload files to the server. It works perfectly fine for small-sized files(~11 MB), it however throws 2032 stream error when size increases beyond that. I tried increasing the requestTimeout param for Httpservice, but it does not seem to be working. It throws the Faultevent exactly after 60 seconds.

I have changed the PHP config settings to the max values. The upload to the server also fails.

I saw many links - eg : [Flex HTTPService times out anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820715/flex-httpservice-times-out-anyway][1]) but none of them is helping much.

I am using Flex 4.6 and AIR 15.0.0.356

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try the suggestion in the accepted answer of the link you provided?

Comment: Yes, it does not recognize the URLRequestDefaults as it is not an AIR application.

Comment: Has anyone faced the same issue and found a solution to it?