# Why am I getting Error #2032 in my Adobe Air application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I am working on an Adobe Air desktop app. I am getting an Error (Error #2032) when attempting a back-end call using...

```
<mx:HTTPService id="xmlReadDownloadSizeObject"
    resultFormat="xml"
    result="xmlDownloadSizeResultEvent(event)"
    fault="xmlDownloadSizeFaultEvent(event)"

public function askDownloadSize(xmlString:String):void
{
    var xmlParam:XML = new XML("<files>" + xmlString + "</files>");
    globaltotalSize = 0;
    xmlReadDownloadSizeObject.url = mainDataURL + "downloadsize.ashx";
    xmlReadDownloadSizeObject.method = "POST";
    xmlReadDownloadSizeObject.contentType = "application/xml"
    xmlReadDownloadSizeObject.send(xmlParam);
}
```

mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent

faultDetail "Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost:5800/downloadsize.ashx" errorID=2032]. URL: http://localhost:5800/downloadsize.ashx"

This error began happening when I changed the back-end call to a copy of the website application on my local machine (http://localhost:5800/downloadsize.ashx). I was initially calling the server directly (https://www.serverName.com/Marathon/).

I have been trying to figure this bug out for an entire day now and am near throwing my hands up in the air! If someone can offer some helpful insight, I would greatly appreciate it!

Let me know if you need some more information. Thanks

Comment: Try to verify that your file is accessible in the browser.

Comment: It seems as though the back-end code was taking too long to respond. These links helped a great deal...http://nightlycoding.com/index.php/2014/05/tip-as3-flex-error-2032-stream-error/    and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820715/flex-httpservice-times-out-anyway

Comment: If so, probably document what have you done to resolve the issue as an answer to this question. You'll likely get some respect for this.

Answer (score 0):

The operation took longer than usual so I changed the max execution time by setting...

```
import flash.net.URLRequestDefaults;
URLRequestDefaults.idleTimeout = 1200000; // or any amount of time in ms
```

It should also be noted that Only Adobe® AIR® content running in the application security sandbox can use the URLRequestDefaults class. Other content will result in a SecurityError being thrown when accessing the members or properties of this class.

See [Adobe live docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestDefaults.html)

Comment: Where does one set these values in your application?

Answer (score 0):

For folks that came here from Google search:

I have been getting error 2032 while installing an Adobe Air application because the filename provided was incorrect. So the second step while resolving the error would be to check the URL.